# Compute all the sets of 87248 into 10 parts

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, set-partition

How many sets are possible? I have to compute all the sets of 87248 into 10 parts

(Additional conditions which may be useful are: integers can be repeated, every integer is less than or equal to 65536, order is not important)

What is the increase in complexity of this kind of problem if number of parts in each set is increased to 20 or 30?

I have a trouble in understanding number theory, this solution will help me in my self motivated research. I am non technical. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean a set of size 87248?

Comment: Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion. Note that at most 1 part can have size larger than 65536. If there was no size restriction, then there are $87258 \choose 10$ ways (assuming restriction to non-negative integers.

Comment: @AndrewD i mean number of possible sets with size of 10 integers that sum to 87428.

Comment: @CalvinLin i should also mention they are all positive integers. can you guess the approximate order of the problem, like approximately, 10 power n will be the number of sets. I am too confused with number theory, incapacity brain!

Comment: Do you have $87\,248$ beans or $87\,248$ individuals? Is a "part" an anonymus bag containing some stuff, or does it have a label, say a number between $1$ and $10\>$?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the restriction to parts of less than $64k$ for the moment, the number of [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $87428$ into $10$ parts is ${87427 \choose 9}$.  To estimate this, we can just [ask Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=87247%20choose%209) and find it is about $8.07 \cdot 10^{38}$ or say it is about $\frac {87427^9}{9!}$.  The base $10$ log of this is about $9 \log_{10}87427-\log_{10}362880\approx 38.907$

The restriction to parts smaller than $64k$ will matter very little.  Let $n$ be the part greater than $64k$.  We have ${87427-n \choose 8}$ ways to compose the rest, then $10$ places to put the big part.  So we need to subtract $\sum_{n=65537}^{87419}10{87427-n \choose 8}$  We can bound this by noting that the first term is the largest, so will just take that term times the number of terms.  $\sum_{n=65537}^{87419}10{87427-n \choose 8} \lt 218830\cdot 1.306\cdot 10^{30}\approx 2.86\cdot 10^{35}$ so the subtraction is less than one part in $2800$

If the number of parts increases, the difficulty of the problem does not increase.  Just change the $9$'s to one less than the number of parts.  As long as the number of parts is quite small compared to $87248$, the multiplier in front of $\log_{10}87247$ will increase, so the approximate answer for $m$ parts will be $\frac{87247^m}{m!}$  The statement that the correction for $64k$ will be small remains true.

Comment: I get some clue there. further, Does [Delannoy Number theory](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.9#E3)  apply to this problem ?                          it says "the number of partitions of n into at most k parts, each less than or equal to m is equal to the number of lattice paths from (0,0) to (m,k) that have exactly vertices n vertices

Comment: I asked about complexity because I have to find out one desired set out of all the possible sets. If the number of possible sets is in the order of 10^38, any idea how long it takes for computation. any idea of its time complexity please?

Comment: What do you mean to find one required set out of all sets?  Are you imagining that there is a list of all the sets somewhere and you need to find the position of the required one in the list?  The list can't exist-it is *far* too big.  But you could define some well structured order on the imagined list, then find the position of a given set without too much trouble.

Comment: thanks @Ross Millikan, the responses were helpful. And you are right, I am looking to find reach a specific position on the imagined list.

Comment: You have to define an order on the list.  One likely one is [licographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which starts with the smallest value.  The first element would be $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,21704,65536$, then $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,21705,65545$ and so on.  From the technique above, you can calculate how many partitions start with $1$-you just split 87247 into 9 parts less than 65536.  If the partition you want to look up starts with 2, count that many.  Then see how deep into the list you are.  This is made for dynamic programming.  It won't take that much computation.

Comment: If you are splitting $n$ into $m$ parts, I would guess order $m^3$ and some $\log n$ factors or so.

Comment: Now @Ross Millikan is hitting the bulls eye that I am struggling with. Great. This helped me in my learning.

Comment: you said that using dynamic programming does'nt take that much computing, so am I correct in thinking that i can reach a required position in an imagined set of approximately 10^38 possible combinations in less than two seconds using dynamic computation. I may be naive in asking this time complexity question.

Comment: I will elaborate my doubt @Ross Millikan. If I have to reach (2, 6, 32, 65, 546, 546, 3248, 4322, 12981, 65500) set, which forms a total of 87248 out of all other possible sets of 10 integers. I will reach this set utilising an additional condition such as the sum of squares of set is 447804117. what will be time taken to reach this set.. two seconds? or ten seconds? any idea of time complexity? please

Comment: I don't think the sum of squares helps.  As I said, you would figure out how many sets start with $1$.  Then among those, find the number that have second entry $1$ through $5$.  Among those, those that have third entry $1$ through $31$ and so on.  It is the same calculation, with the number of pieces decreasing each time, so will terminate.  If you want an exact answer, you need a big number package and you need to do the sum for the sets that have a number too large exactly.

Comment: okay I understand. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Start with a simpler problem - divide 10 into 10 parts.  Then 11 into 10 parts. And so on.

That leads to [A026816](http://oeis.org/A026816) and [A008639](http://oeis.org/A008639), from which you can get a generating function for the answer.

Comment: Depends if you're looking for Partitions or Compositions.  Compositions is considerably easier.  The above gives Partitions.

Comment: im looking for partitions

Comment: Then these sequences give the answer you want.

Comment: Those sequences give answer with greatest part 10. My greatest part for instance is 65536. I was wondering if the Delannoy Number(http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.9#E3)is of any use here

Comment: Look at both -- "greatest part 10" and "ten parts" winds up being equivalent.  They are the same sequence.  The second one is the "ten part" version, but both have useful formulas for you.

Comment: I overlooked that in anxiety, thanks again @Ed Pegg!